# Add vertical text to the left of a figure with subcaption

Tags: subcaption, subfig

I would like to add text, such as `My Y variable' to the left of the following figure (where I put the red mark):

[image: MWE without the left text]

Here is the MWE I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[luatex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
    \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{aboveskip=5pt,belowskip=20pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A1}[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{A2}[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{A3}[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    \subcaptionbox{A4}[.48\textwidth]{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
    My x variable
    \caption{Whatever caption here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Does anyone has an idea? I guess tikz could be an option, but I am open to anything simpler!

Comment: Welcome. // Please try yourself: your code can‘t compile on other peoples computers, and add the missing parts. // Look for \marginnote.

Comment: `graphics` and `graphicx` provide `\rotatebox`.

Comment: You provide only a code fragment not an MWE. PLease extend it to complete small document - MWE - which we can compile as it is.

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, I took the code from my whole document. I modified my question to truly have a MWE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I corectly understood you, than you looking for something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb] 
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.45\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.05\linewidth}\centering
\rotatebox[origin=center]{90}{My y variable}
\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\centering
    \subfloat[A1]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[A2]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    
    \subfloat[A3]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
    \hfil
    \subfloat[A4]{\includegraphics{example-image-b}}
    
    My x variable
\end{minipage}
    \caption{Whatever caption here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first minipage isn't needed if you use `[origin=c]` instead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, you are right. Corrected now.

Comment: @Zarko Yes, it is exactly what I needed! I should have thought about minipage...